# Linux Mint 18 lose internet connection

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I have a HP Pavillion DV-7 laptop equipped with Intel 1030 WiFi card, Linux Mint 18 on it, and a Huawei HG8245T router. The problem is linux often lose connection. For example if I run

```
ping ya.ru
```

while mostly it works just fine occasionally it can say

```
ping: unknown host ya.ru
```

I made a couple of tests and found out that the problem persist on linux distros with kernel 4.4.0 (tried some Ubuntu versions as well as others). Distros with 3.x or 4.5 or above kernel are working fine. I upgraded my kernel from 4.4.0 to 4.7.3 but this didn't help. Other distros with different kernel version don't have this problem, i.e. Fedora 24 (kernel 4.5) works fine as well as many others. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please , add the output of `iwconfig`

Comment: wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"mgts278"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: E4:68:A3:B1:46:B3   
          Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:49   Missed beacon:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `resolvconf` package:

```
apt-get install resolvconf
```

Edit your `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` by adding the following line:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` add:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

Run :

```
resolvconf -u
```

Restart networking :

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Unfortunately these settings do nothing. Power management is still on and connection problems still exist.

Comment: When I do "iwconfig wlan0 power off" it actually turns off power management, but errors are still present. If I run "ping ya.ru" it randomly fails with the "unknown host error". So I suppose problem lies elsewhere? I install Linux Mint 17.3 on the other partition and WiFi works there just fine. Power management is off there by default, and when I turn it on it still works without errors.

Comment: Run `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` then ping again

Comment: WoW! This really helps! But it reverts back to default on reboot. How can I make changes permanent?